# Updating angular 2.0.1 to 2.4

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to update angular in my project, from 2.0.1 to 2.4.5. I changed the version in the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "Frontend project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e-live": "protractor --elementExplorer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.4.5",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.15.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.4",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "gulp-jasmine": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.4.0",
    "jszip": "2.6.0",
    "ng2-translate": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.5.1",
    "symbol-observable": "0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "traceur": "0.0.96",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.5",
    "browser-sync": "2.11.1",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-debug": "2.0.1",
    "gulp-inject": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-newer": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.0.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "0.5.4",
    "gulp-rimraf": "0.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "2.0.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.5.1",
    "gulp-traceur": "0.17.2",
    "gulp-tslint": "1.5.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.5.1",
    "gulp-vulcanize": "6.1.0",
    "gulp-war": "0.1.2",
    "gulp-webserver": "0.9.1",
    "gulp-zip": "3.1.0",
    "karma": "1.1.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "1.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-renamer-preprocessor": "0.0.1",
    "live-server": "0.9.0",
    "mocha": "2.3.4",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
    "protractor": "3.0.0",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.34",
    "traceur": "0.0.96",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "typings": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```

But I got this issue while running npm install :

> npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.10.0 failed (this is
>   probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
>   'C:\Users\LOU\Projects\spas2-backend\frontends\cockpit\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
>   npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.1
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.1 requires a peer of
>   @angular/common@2.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.1 requires a peer
>   of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.1 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.1
>   requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   angular2-google-maps@0.15.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.21 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN ng2-translate@3.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN ng2-translate@3.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@~2.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN The package traceur is included as both a dev and production
>   dependency. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> audited 15439 packages in 90.584s found 290 vulnerabilities (124 low,
>   101 moderate, 63 high, 2 critical)   run `npm audit fix` to fix them,
>   or `npm audit` for deta
>
> ils

Thank you

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: I fixed by clean the cache and install again with npm install

Comment: If you are using npm, I recommend you to delete the package-lock.json before installing the packages view `npm install`, it was often the cause of my problem when I using npm, and most likely the reason why I switched to yarn, which is also faster on Windows.